# Best performance: count in a loop or outside?

Tags: php, benchmarking, php-5.6, php-7

Perhaps this question has been asked several times but I can't find a proper answer here or in Google so apologies if this is a dupe or something like that but here I go...

What's the best way to achieve performance in a loop:

1. `count($var)` each time

   ```
   for ($i=0;$i<count($var);$i++) {
       // do something
   }
   ```
2. put a var outside and use that var:

   ```
   $cnt = count($var);
   for ($i=0;$i<$var;$i++) {
       // do something
   }
   ```

Is there any PHP script or code to show execution times and so on? I mean something for benchmark and see the results on this cases?

Comment: Why don't you run some tests and see?

Comment: @j08691 that's because I don't know how to benchmark it properly for see execution times and memory and so on and that's why I asked about this and thanks for the downvote (to the person who did) ;)

Comment: Thanks for assuming that I downvoted you -- but I didn't.

Comment: see here: http://www.phpbench.com/ - use `count()` outside the `for`

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you meant

`for ($i=0;$i<$cnt;$i++) {`

in the second snippet

yes... it's more efficient to only do the count once.

it can also be done like so

```
for ($i=0, $cnt=count($var); $i<$cnt; $i++) {
```